# Add geom_text into geom_dotplot 's dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a dataset that resembles my own :

```
set.seed(1)
CRD2 <- data.frame(Response = c(rnorm(10, 5, 1), rnorm(10, 4, 1), rnorm(10, 3, 1)),
                   Treatment = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10)),
                   Labels = rep(1:5, each = 2))
```

Using ggplot2 I made the following plot with the code below:

```
CRD2 %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = Response, fill = Treatment)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center") + 
        geom_text(aes(label = Labels), size = 3, fontface = "bold")
```

[image]

**My expected output** is to produce a plot in which, for every level of 'Treatment', all the observations that have the same 'Response' value are put side by side but *aligned to the center of the boxplot*. In addition to that, I want the values of the 'Labels' variable of my dataset to be inside of each of the dots.

So far, the `geom_dotplot()` function is the one that gives me all the observations with the same 'Response' value in the possition I want. However, I can't make the text to be inside the dot. I have no need to stick to `geom_dotplot` or `geom_text` so whatever suggestion is welcomed :)

---

**What I've tried so far :** In addition to the code to produce the plot above, I also tried using `geom_point` and `geom_text` with the same jitter, as is shown in the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
CRD2 %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = Response, fill = Treatment)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        geom_point(aes(color = Treatment), position = position_jitter(width = 0.5, height = 0), size = 3) + 
        geom_text(aes(label = Labels), size = 3, fontface = "bold", position = position_jitter(width = 0.5, height = 0))
```

[image]

However, it didn't produce the plot I'm expecting to generate since the dots are not aligned to the center and there is no way to make the label to be inside the dots even if I use the same width for the jitter of both, `geom_text` and `geom_point`.

---

**EDIT :** I changed the title from "add labels inside dots aligned to the center of each boxplot" to "Add geom_text into geom_dotplot 's dots" because this is closer to what I wanted originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not generally possible to get the text inside the dots generated by `geom_dotplot` because of the way that it is drawn. Often in ggplot, one can apply the same `stat_` transformation to points layers and text layers, but `geom_dotplot` has its own custom grob and recalculates its position every time the window is resized. You therefore cannot use it with `geom_text`.

You could simply work out the positions yourself of course:

```r
CRD2 %>%
  mutate(Response_round = round(5 * Response) / 5) %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Response_round) %>% 
  mutate(x = 0.1 * (seq_along(Response_round) - (0.5 * (n() + 1)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(x = x + as.numeric(as.factor(Treatment))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = Response, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 6, aes(x = x, y = Response_round)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Labels, x = x, y = Response_round), size = 4, 
            fontface = "bold")
```

[image]

You can achieve your second method, of lining up the random jitter of points and text using the `seed` argument of `position_jitter`

```r
CRD2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = Response, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 5,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0, seed = 1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Labels), size = 3, fontface = "bold", 
            position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0, seed = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Given a similar recent question, I am waiting for geomtextpath::geom_textcircle ;)

Comment: Your first plot looks really awesome :O . I have a two question about it: (1st) What is the rationale behind using `round(5 * Response) / 5`  instead of just `round(response, 1)`? I tried with both and the resulting plot changed but I don't know why. (2nd) Is there a way to change how close two values of 'Response' have to be in order to be ploted side by side? In my real data (which I cannot share) there are some values that are really close but are not binned into the same 'Response' value. Thank you, your answer is already very helpful

Comment: @bpvalderrama the `round(5 * Response) / 5` rounds to the nearest 0.2, whereas `round(response, 1)` rounds to the nearest 0.1. You can try various values of n in `round(n * Response)/n` to get the binning as you would like it. No matter where you bin data, the breaks have to be somewhere, so there will always be instances when points that are close together don't get binned together. The larger your bins (i.e. the smaller then `n` in the equation above), the better chance you have of binning close numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If switching to an other package is an option for you then maybe the `ggbeeswarm` package offers some options to get a plot similar to `geom_dotplot`.

One option would be `geom_quasirandom` if similar to `geom_point` you want to show all data points:

```r
library(ggbeeswarm)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
CRD2 <- data.frame(Response = c(rnorm(10, 5, 1), rnorm(10, 4, 1), rnorm(10, 3, 1)),
                   Treatment = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 10)),
                   Labels = rep(1:5, each = 2))

ggplot(CRD2, aes(x = Treatment, y = Response, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_quasirandom(size = 5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Labels), size = 3, fontface = "bold", color = "white", position = position_quasirandom())
```

[image]

A second option would be to manually do the binning of the data and use `geom_beeswarm`:

```r
library(dplyr)

CRD2 <- CRD2 |> 
  mutate(Response_binned = cut_width(Response, width = 1/10 * diff(range(Response)))) |> 
  group_by(Response_binned) |> 
  mutate(Response_binned_mean = mean(Response))

ggplot(CRD2, aes(x = Treatment, y = Response, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(y = Response_binned_mean), size = 5, cex = 4, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Labels, y = Response_binned_mean), size = 3, fontface = "bold", color = "white", position = position_beeswarm(cex = 4))
```

[image]